# Gravity Forms: Showing specific date years

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity forms (Wordpress) and I want to know is there a way, that I can show specific dates in the year date dropdown?  I want to show only `2014 2015 and 2016`.  I have googled and cannot find anything - I dont mind if its a jquery function that has to be appended.

Answer (score 3):

If your Date field input type is set to Date Drop Down you can use the [gform_date_min_year](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_date_min_year) and [gform_date_max_year](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_date_max_year) hooks to restrict the range of years available in the year drop down.

You would place the following in your theme functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'gform_date_max_year', 'set_max_year' );
function set_max_year( $max_year ) {
    return 2016;
}
add_filter( 'gform_date_min_year', 'set_min_year' );
function set_min_year( $min_year ) {
    return 2014;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this. Add to your functions.php

```
/* ------------------------------------ */
add_filter( 'gform_date_max_year', 'set_max_year' );
function set_max_year( $max_year ) {
    $year = date("Y");
    return $year + 10;
}
add_filter( 'gform_date_min_year', 'set_min_year' );
function set_min_year( $min_year ) {
    $year = date("Y");
    return $year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see here a jquery function is handling it for all datepickers in your gravity form:

`wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/datepicker.js`

this is based on `class` of html element, now you have two ways to complete your requirement:

> 1. Edit the above js file(I have mentioned.)
> 2. Or write a js function based on id of the Element which is generated by Gravity forms
>         plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured this out yet but I stumbled upon your question while trying to figure out the same thing. Go to `plugins > gravityforms >  js > datepicker.min.js` (it's not a lot of code) and change:

```
yearRange:"2015:2016"
```